# how to loop back to scetion if this is outcome

Tags: python-3.x

I want to loop the end section of the code if you get the 'Error, class not found'. I already tried a, for and while loop but i couldn't get it working.

```
Health = 0
Damage = 0
Classes = ['Mage','Knight']
Class = ''
print('Select Character Name.')
Name = input()
print('Hello',Name,'please choose your class.')
print('')
print('Mage: 5 Health: 7 Damage')
print('Knight: 7 Health : 5 Damage')

#looped section
Select = input()
if Select in ['Mage']:
        print('Mage Selected')
        Health = 5
        Damage = 7
        Class = 'Mage'
elif Select in ['Knight']:
        print('Knight Selected')
        Health = 7
        Damage = 5
        Class = 'Knight'
else:

    print('Error, class not found')
#loop back if this is outcome
```

Comment: how did u try to do while loop.

Comment: well this can be acheved using infinite while loop (while True:) and to make sure that you break the loop at certain cercomectances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when facing problems like this, your default approach should be a while loop making sure that the loop will go on (virtually forever) if the defined conditions aren't met. so this is what you can do:

```
while True:
    # looped section
    Select = input()
    if Select in ['Mage']:
            print('Mage Selected')
            Health = 5
            Damage = 7
            Class = 'Mage'
            break # break the loop if selection is correct
    elif Select in ['Knight']:
            print('Knight Selected')
            Health = 7
            Damage = 5
            Class = 'Knight'
            break # break the loop if selection is correct
    else:
        print('Error, class not found, try again: ') # will start the loop over
```